# How to grant permission to audio in electron app in Windows?

Tags: javascript, audio, permissions, electron, microphone

I'm trying to implement speech recognition into the electron application. The solution works in chrome browser, but does not work in electron. The application stops listening immediately - it probably has no microphone permission. How to grant permissions?

index.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = electron;

let mainWindow;


ipcMain.on('close-me', (evt, arg) => {
    app.quit()
})

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        transparent: true,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webviewTag: true
        }
    });


    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'web/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);


});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <button id="rec"> rec</button>
        <button id="endrec"> end</button>

    </div>
    <script src="scripts/speech.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

speech.js

```
const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.lang = 'pl-PL';
const rec = document.querySelector('#rec');
const endrec = document.querySelector('#endrec');

    recognition.onstart = function () {
        console.log('I started');
    }

    recognition.onend = function () {
        console.log('I finished');
    }

    recognition.onresult = function () {
        console.log('Take what I recorded');
        console.log(event);

        const current = event.resultIndex;
        const transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
        console.log(transcript);

    }

    rec.addEventListener('click', () => {
        recognition.start();
        console.log('You clicked me');
    })

    endrec.addEventListener('click', () => {
        recognition.stop();
    })
```

I've also tried solutions with

```
webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function (e) {
     if (e.permission === 'media') {
         e.request.allow();
    }
});
```

and

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ audio: true })
```

UPDATE

---

I found a reason to stop recognizing - error - network

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem in the end as im having the same problem?

Comment: any solution on this problem ?

Comment: unfortunatelly nope

Comment: I'm having similar issue on Linux. Did you find the solution?

Comment: unfortunatelly nope

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use the [`setPermissionRequestHandler`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#4-handle-session-permission-requests-from-remote-content) on your session, like this:

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {
    app,
    BrowserWindow,
    ipcMain,
    session
} = electron;

let mainWindow;


ipcMain.on('close-me', (evt, arg) => {
    app.quit()
})

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        transparent: true,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webviewTag: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'web/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);

    session.fromPartition("default").setPermissionRequestHandler((webContents, permission, callback) => {
        let allowedPermissions = ["audioCapture"]; // Full list here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#manifest

        if (allowedPermissions.includes(permission)) {
            callback(true); // Approve permission request
        } else {
            console.error(
                `The application tried to request permission for '${permission}'. This permission was not whitelisted and has been blocked.`
            );

            callback(false); // Deny
        }
    });
});
```

### edit 4/7/2023

It appears the permission is named [`desktopCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/) now to capture audio.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I'm providing a repository for you to test

https://github.com/darekdede1995/electron-mirror-desktop

Comment: Hi @reZach , Did I missed something ? I didn't found any permission named `audioCapture` in the Link you mentioned. Full list here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#manifest   thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang - Looks like it's called `desktopCapture` now: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem myself and found out that google doesn't provide speechAPI for CLI based apps like electron. Your best bet is to use either [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) or any third-party API like [Microsoft Cognitive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/).

Answer (score -2):

Are you testing on MacOS? I faced a similar issue in my MBP, and below check solved the issue -

```
systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess(microphone)
```

See the [Electron doc reference](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences#systempreferencesaskformediaaccessmediatype-macos) for additional details.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am testing on Windows